# Pure CSS box collapse in specific way

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I need to collapse divs (left: logo, banner, right: buttons group A, buttons group B)

I want these to collapse in specific way depending on screen size:

1. Button group B collapse
2. Banner collapse

If screen resolution is super high I want to have banner+logo on left (red+green), blank space in middle, and two button groups on right (blue+purple)

See image below:

[image]

This is what I have tried so far:

https://jsfiddle.net/ey74wud6/

To be honest it was trial and error, and boxes are collapsing in way not good for me.

```
<style>
    /* just example - color, fixed size of box */
    .green { background: green; width: 80px; height: 70px; }
    .red { background: red; width: 270px; height: 70px; }    
    .purple { background: purple; width: 70px; height: 70px; }
    .blue { background: blue; width: 70px; height: 70px; }
    .box { margin: 2px; }

    /* proper css experiments */

    .left {
        float: left;
    }

    .left .box {
        float: left;
    }

    .right {
        float: right;
    }

    .right .box {
        float: left;
    }
</style>

<div class="left">        
    <div class="box green"></div>
</div>

<div class="left">        
    <div class="box red"></div>
</div>

<div class="right">        
    <div class="box purple"></div>
</div>

<div class="right">        
    <div class="box blue"></div>
</div>
```

**I know I can do it with little help of javascript but my question is it possible to solve my problem using pure CSS?**

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Possibly css media quries can help here

Comment: will those blocks have a fixed height? (no dinamic content)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css media queries for this. Check out the modified example: https://jsfiddle.net/ey74wud6/1/

I've modified your css code a bit, but the most important part is :

```
@media (max-width: 454px) {
    .left {
         width : 280px;
    }

    .right {
        width: 80px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 455px) and (max-width: 522px) {
    .left {
         width : 360px;
    }

    .right {
        width: 80px;
    }
}
```

You can replace the values to fit your needs

Answer (score 0):

What you need is display:flex

You can define flex-shrink/grow and combine it with max- and min-width on flexible Elements.

And you can combine that with mediaqueries